# Why a table type parameter is not getting declared in sp?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertInvoices] 


        @ServiceIDs as dbo.ServiceIDs READONLY,
```

But it doesn't get declared and throws error:

> Msg 2715, Level 16, State 3, Procedure InsertInvoices, Line 18 Column,
>   parameter, or variable #8: Cannot find data type dbo.ServiceIDs.
>   Parameter or variable '@ServiceIDs' has an invalid data type.

even though I have declared a table type.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ServicesIDs] AS TABLE(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ServiceID] [int] NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
GO
```

Comment: Why there is an `as` between `@ServiceIDs` and `dbo.ServiceIDs`?

Comment: @Ivien removed as but still not working

Comment: Tested with  following  test  SP . It is  working.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertInvoices]
     @ServiceIDs As ServicesIDs READONLY
AS
BEGIN 
 Print  'test'        
END

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is on you spelling. Your type is [dbo].[ServicesIDs] but you use @ServiceIDs. The problem is 's' character.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertInvoices] 


        @ServiceIDs as dbo.ServicesIDs READONLY,
```

Answer (score 1):

It is just not working because of a typo:
Your type is called `[dbo].[ServicesIDs]` but you are trying to use it as `dbo.ServiceIDs` (notice the missing 's' in the `Services`!

Try this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertInvoices] 
   @ServiceIDs as dbo.ServicesIDs READONLY,
```